# celery task not acnowledged after warm shutdown of worker

Tags: django, celery, djcelery

I'm new to djcelery development.
I want to shutdown a worker from a button on the web interface. So I'm calling the following task when the button is clicked in tasks.py:

```
result = broadcast('shutdown', destination=[worker.hostname])
```

I notice if the worker as an active task, it's not shutdown immediately, it'll be down after the task execution has been completed. However, the task state is always "STARTED". And if I restart the worker, the task will be picked up again and executed.
Is there anyway I can have the task state updated since it's already been executed?
I do have CELERY_ACKS_LATE set to True.

An update:
The celery version I'm using is 3.0.9 (Chiastic Slide), and I'm using Rabbitmq as the broker.

Comment: Please share your celery version and what transport, result layers do you use.